# Need to know what is the best practice for registering commands

Tags: java, design-patterns, command, pattern-matching, minecraft

I have a very specific situation. The context of the situation is I am building a plugin for Minecraft and I have hit a bit of a design problem. I have built a hierarchy of abstract classes, interfaces, and their derived concrete classes (in Java if it matters). Here is a general idea of the structure:

**public interface ICommandUsage, ICommandPattern, IPermissionNode**

(these are implemented so that each command must define a proper usage of the command, follow a certain pattern to match with regex, and have a permission node so that the command sender can use the command or not)

**public abstract class Command = The base class**

**public abstract class ConsoleCommand = A derived subset of Command class**

**public abstract class PlayerCommand = A derived subset of Command class**

**public abstract class UserCommand = A derived subset of PlayerCommand**

**public abstract class ServerAdminCommand = A derived subset of PlayerCommand**

The rest of the classes are various concrete implementations defining the functions from the interfaces and abstract classes.

Here is my dilema: Upon starting the plugin, the "main" class registers *all* of the commands so that when a user issues a command, the commandDelegate can then interpret the command via pattern matching. The pattern matching comes from the method getPattern() which returns a String that is semi-hard-coded into each concrete class.

My logic is that each concrete class should be responsible for their own patterns, permission nodes and usages, so these methods should exists *in the classes themselves*.

The main problem is that when I register the commands in the main class, I have to pass in null arguments to the constructors to create a 'fake' command...

i.e. **registerCommand("console_info", new ConsoleInfo(null, null));**

I recognize that this is a bad practice, but I am at a loss for where to look in order to find a solution. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Java allows for you to make multiple constructors for a single class as long as each constructor takes a different type or types of arguments. for instance

```
public class Thing {

private int value;

public Thing(int i) {
    value = i;
}
public Thing() {
    value = 0;
}
}
```

So rather than constructing the class with two null values for it's arguments, create a constructor with no arguments and deal with that case within the class. This will make it easy to change if in the future you decide to change standards for the case when the class is built with no arguments.

Comment: I initially had it where each of the concrete classes had their own empty constructors, however I ended up just setting the two fields to null inside the empty constructor, which I believe is still a bad practice. I was more wondering if there was a better pattern to follow...